# How to create EBNF grammar for a list in xtext?

Tags: xtext, bnf, ebnf

I m trying to create a list in xtext, If anybody can help me to create a grammar for that, it will be really helpful. I tried writing this but its not the xtext format so i getting errors on that.

```
List:
'List' name=ID type = Nlist;

Nlist:
   Array | Object
;

Array:
    {Array} "[" values*=Value[','] "]"
 ;

Value:
   STRING | FLOAT | BOOL | Object | Array | "null"
 ;

Object:
   "{" members*=Member[','] "}"
 ;

Member:
   key=STRING ':' value=Value
```

I m new to this one, Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the default syntax for comma separated lists is e.g.

```
MyList: '#[' (elements+=Element (',' elements+=Element )*)? ']';
```

Comment: Hi  Thanks @Christian Dietrich , so if i want to add operations on the list like getItem(0), how can we add that ?

Comment: i dont get that question. grammar and typesystem are two things. so simply add methods calls to the thing

Comment: Thank you. I just started this. So bit confused about all of it.

Comment: Hi Where can i add these typesystem ? is that in the entity.java file ? Sorry if i m asking a stupid question.

Comment: first you need to allow it in the grammar, then ususally in validator/scope provider (your grammar snippet does not show any hint what you have already)

Comment: Value:
    {Value} STRING |  Object | Array | {Value} "null" | Value "." ID '(' (params+=Value ("," params+=Value)*)?  ')';   This what you meant by 
 allowing validators right ?

Comment: I tried adding that but its throwing an error saying grammar is left recursive.

Comment: did you give e.g. https://www.typefox.io/blog/parsing-expressions-with-xtext a read?

Comment: also https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-2nd-examples/blob/master/org.example.smalljava.parent/org.example.smalljava/src/org/example/smalljava/SmallJava.xtext might be a good starting point

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look at it and get back to you.

Comment: i have one more doubt, how can I run the generated language ?